# Ubuntu 18.04 detecting external monitor but suddenly getting blue screen/NO SIGNAL

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I am new to Ubuntu, so apologies for any noob mistakes here.

I am running 18.04 from an Asus laptop (graphics card: Intel HD Graphics 615). I initially connected it to an external Asus monitor via HDMI and used it without any problems. One day the external monitor stopped working, without my having made any changes - I now get only blue screen and "HDMI NO SIGNAL" on the external. (The external monitor works fine via HDMI with other laptops; the laptop has the same connection issue with other monitors.)

What is confusing is the `xrandr` output - below - suggests that the external monitor is detected and active.

As per other threads have suggested, I have tried:

- updating Ubuntu
- changing the display settings via the Ubuntu settings and arandr
- changing my Desktop Manager to LightDM and back again
- looking for proprietary drivers and installing Displaylink

I am completely stuck. I'd be hugely grateful for any suggestions!

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5120 x 1800, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.70*+
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+3200+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.95  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

Comment: OK, it seems my problem was actually a faulty connection... the HDMI-to-mini HDMI adaptor had a loose connection, so the computer could detect the external display but there was no output. Solved with a new adaptor.